# Surround an object with particles using Geometry nodes rather than a particle system

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to surround an object in a cloud of particles using geometry nodes?

I chose geometry nodes rather than the built in particle system because the built in system doesn't allow particles to take the shape of the fluid.

I want random colored tiles in a cloud around this "corruption fluid", but I can't find a way to have them select the volume around it rather than on or inside it. Any help is greatly appreciated (ignore the annotations+text)

i.e I want the particles to create a cloud around the object, within the bounds of the volumetric using geometry nodes. They don't have to have a specific pattern, but just need to float around the vicinity of the fluid sim, like a cloud.

[image: screenshot of rough idea]

Comment: i am not sure what you want to achieve? something like saturn rings? particles flying around an object?

Comment: I want the particles to create a cloud around the object, within the bounds of the volumetric using geometry nodes. They don't have to have a specific pattern, but just need to float around the vicinity of the fluid sim, like a cloud.